# How to Identify column names in terminal commands

Tags: linux, grep, terminal, man, filter

Sometimes its useful to select/de-select specific columns from a command output data, but the columns are not always listed by name in the manpages. How can we find the names?

*For example*

Running two commands to demonstrate output

```bash
$ sudo journalctl -eu NetworkManager -o short
Feb 06 06:52:56 user NetworkManager[713]: <info>  [1707206156.8193] device (tun0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Feb 06 06:52:56 user NetworkManager[713]: <info>  [1707206156.8195] device (tun0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Feb 06 06:52:56 user NetworkManager[713]: <info>  [1707206156.8207] device (tun0): Activation: successful, device activated.
```

This output appears to contain 6 different columns (pseudo-naming to highlight)

**date, user, process, type, date2, message**

Now if we run a second command `lsblk` we can see the columns already have assigned names.

```bash
$ lsblk
NAME                                          MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
zram0                                         253:0    0   7.3G  0 disk  [SWAP]
nvme0n1                                       259:0    0 238.5G  0 disk
```

and we can select the columns we need by running `--output` with `columns`

```bash
$ lsblk --output NAME,SIZE
NAME                                            SIZE
zram0                                           7.3G
nvme0n1                                       238.5G
```

`man lsblk` page provides help on columns, whereas many other commands do not

```
 -o, --output list
              Specify which output columns to print.  Use --help to get a list of all supported columns.  The columns may affect tree-like output.  The default is to
              use tree for the column 'NAME' (see also --tree).

              The default list of columns may be extended if list is specified in the format +list (e.g., lsblk -o +UUID).
```

How can we identify/name a column (even if we cant select/target it) if its not listed in man pages?

Comment: How to identify: do you mean technically or theoretically?

Comment: I'm not sure there's a *generic* answer to your question, however for the first case there's [man systemd.journal-fields](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.journal-fields.html)

Comment: The `journalctl` log output isn't entirely columnar. Each message starts with a timestamp, the host that issued the log entry, the process name, the PID in `[]` of the issuer and a colon (`:`). Everything after the colon is a free form message from the programmer, intended to help the user understand the program's behavior. Read `man logger`.

Comment: Which column(s) are not listed in which `man` page(s)? Please [edit] your question to add whatever information you get. Do not use Add Comment.

Comment: Many commands also have `info` pages with more information than their `man` pages but don't expect to get column headings for commands whose output that isn't tabular, such as `journalctl`.